# gridview on edit event , on update event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how I can access the edit and the update button from `GridView`?
I mean, if I click the edit button from the website in the `GridView`, I want to get some values from the tables.
For example: the `button1` event.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx what you want to look at is the rowcommand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the GridView rowupdating event.

```cs
protected void myGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
```

The `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` contain properties for `NewValues` and `OldValues`.

I often use the following to cancel the update if nothing has actually been changed.

```cs
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in e.NewValues)
{
    String oldValue = e.OldValues[d.Key] == null ? "" : e.OldValues[d.Key].ToString();
    String newValue = d.Value == null ? "" : d.Value.ToString();
    if (oldValue != newValue)
    {                    
        return; // -- change detected
    }
}
e.Cancel = true; // -- don't execute the update
myGridView.EditIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a rowCommand on your button in template field
2. Check for your command name under rowCommand event
3. Open a database connection & execute SQL/stored procedure to fetch your records

Also if you use a SQLDataSource, it can automatically do it for you if you specify right queries.